# How do I skip one row in an SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm listing products from my database where I select the latest product as a big feature. The rest are sorted by latest product.

So I have two querys which looks like this.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 4
```

However...  This makes the latest product appear twice in my current layout. (The feature).

How do I tell the second query to skip the latest entry?

Comment: Could you show us the php code so we can help?

Comment: Can you avoid issuing two queries and just have one with LIMIT 5? It will have both the latest product (first) and the other four.

Comment: Your second query definitely doesn't look like *that*. See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can specify the `LIMIT` clause to start at second row instead, and then fetch next 4 rows.

```
SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 1,4
```

[Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html) is:

```
[LIMIT {[offset,] row_count | row_count OFFSET offset}]
```

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants With two arguments,
>   the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return,
>   and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return.
>
> The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

Comment: @RaymondNijland `ORDER BY product_id DESC` is there in the query. Maybe you overlooked :-)

Comment: Wow not maybe i pretty much did.. running downstairs to get myself some caffeine to wake up.

Comment: @RaymondNijland btw off-topic to this question, but you may help me here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/223726/160363